# Is there a way to modify this regex to remove any standalone numbers in the beginning of the string?

Tags: python, regex, text-extraction

I am trying to use regex to pick up text in the rows of a table. I use this regex to pick up "Account" column values so that I can use it as a key for a dictionary:

```
account_regex= re.compile(r'^((?:[\d\/]+)?[\w\d\s\.()+&-]+)(?:\s+[\/\.\s]+)?')
```

The problem is that one of the PDFs that I'm trying to extract the table from is missing a row. I load the list of dictionaries in a JSON file in this format:

```
pdf_df.columns= ['Index', 'Account', 'Allocation($)']
pdf_values=pdf_df.to_dict('records')
```

It gives output like this when everything is working fine:

```
Index: 1
Account: "American United Corp LLC"
Allocation: 6.0
}

{
Index:2
Account: "Balkan Asset Mgmt -New York"
Allocation: 11.0
}

{
Index: 3
Account: "Genesis Capital"
Allocation: 18.0
}
```

But maybe because there is a missing row in the table of the pdf I'm trying to extract from, the dictionaries representing the rows after the skipped row show up like this. There is no row 62 in the pdf but the index is working just fine as it increment +1 each row:

```
Index: 62
Account: " 63 Triont Advisers LLC"
Allocation: 6.0
}

{
Index: 63
Account: " 64 Zoya Mgmt Co -New York"
Allocation: 11.0
}

{
Index: 64
Account: " 65 Genesis Capital"
Allocation: 18.0
}
```

The question is, how do I get rid of the standalone numbers like 63,64,65 that start appearing in the account string after that one row that doesn't exist in the PDF I'm extracting text from? So instead of "63 Triont Advisers LLC", I need "Triont Advisers LLC", instead of " 64 Zoya Mgmt Co -New York", I need "Zoya Mgmt Co -New York", etc. Note that the regex works fine all up until that one row that doesn't exist in the original PDF. After that, the row # is also picked up by the regex looking for account name. I cannot modify the regex so much that it excludes ANY type of numbers because sometimes account names do start with numbers. But these numbers in this instance are always connected to an alphanumeric char or special char. So for example, "40/86 Caramel Inc. -New York" should still be matched even though there are numbers starting at the beginning, which the regex I have rn, does pick up. But how can I remove these standalone numbers that appear after the missed row?

I added the function, which seems to do the trick:

```
def clean_account_name(account_name):
    # Remove any standalone numbers at the start of the name
    account_name = re.sub(r'^\d{1,4}(?!\w)', '', account_name).strip()
    return account_name
```

I didn't modify the account_regex. But now, from another PDF, there seems to be a problem. The existing string should be " 40/86 Adverts Inc.- Carmel" but now it populates in a dictionary as "/86 Adverts Inc.- Carmel". What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Hi @Rabiya;
Can you modify the regex line as :

`account_name = re.sub(r'^\d{1,4}(?![\w\/])', '', account_name).strip()`

and let me know if it works ?

Comment: Well,
I will add that an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
^(\d+\s+)(?=.*)
```

This will matches only any number followed by a space.

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Vq6HR1/1)

Answer (score 0):

This pattern `^\d{1,4}(?!\w)` gives a partial match in 40/86 as it can match 40 and after that the assertion is true because `/` is not a word character.

In your initial pattern `^((?:[\d\/]+)?[\w\d\s\.()+&-]+)(?:\s+[\/\.\s]+)?` there are some things to note:

- `\w` also matches `\d`
- You don't have to escape all characters in a character class, just some specific ones
- this `(?:[\d\/]+)?` is the same as `[\d/]*`

The pattern could be shortened to this, and you might also consider to remove or change the last optional part:

```
^[\d/]*[\w\s.()+&-]+(?:\s+[/.\s]+)?
```

---

To remove the standalone numbers at the start of the name, you can remove leading spaces without newlines followed by matching 1 or more digits, again followed by spaces:

```
^[^\S\n]*\d+[^\S\n]+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NZdVLR/1).

```
def clean_account_name(account_name):
    # Remove any standalone numbers at the start of the name
    return re.sub(r'^[^\S\n]*\d+[^\S\n]+', '', account_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

> But now, from another PDF, there seems to be a problem. The existing
> string should be " 40/86 Adverts Inc.- Carmel" but now it populates in
> a dictionary as "/86 Adverts Inc.- Carmel". What can I do to fix this?

You can change the regex line as :

```
account_name = re.sub(r'^\d{1,4}(?![\w\/])', '', account_name).strip()
```

This shall remove any standalone numbers at the start of the name